# Cross Correlation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution, cross-correlation

I was asked to implement the `cross correlation` in Matlab and compare it with the `xcorr` that `Matlab` provides.

From what I have searched its seems that cross correlation is similar to `convolution` but I still don’t fully understand how either of them work, so its impossible to get it down on code.

If somebody has done this before and is willing to share the code with a explanation on how it works is appreciated.

PS: I was told that I cant be using `inbuilt` functions other than the simple ones.(for, if, etc..)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Google it, figure it out, and come back with questions about programming.

Comment: In the best case this is a basic math question, not a programming question. Make sure to know what you need to program, then you can ask questions here if you get stuck doing this. If you want to know more about the `xcorr` function just type `doc xcorr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you are familiar with this GIF from a convolution: [image: Thanks Wikipedia]

What do you see there? you calculate the value under two functions *(the realtion between them is a multiplication)*, which is an integral *(which in discrete system is a sum of the values inside your integration limits)*, and you do that for the whole integration limit in one function *(so that's one inner loop)* in every step of the integration limits of the other function , for the whole integration limit of the second function (*nested in a second loop*).

So there you have it, a convolution can be programmed as the sum of multiplications of the values of two functions inside two nested loops over the integration limits. For the cross correlation you just change one direction.

Try programming that and come back if it doesn't work. Good luck with your assignment!